# PHP adding array values to multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-push

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array push with associate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618150/array-push-with-associate-array)

I am trying to design a php program to crawl a website and recursively follow all links until the entire website is searched. To accomplish this, I am trying to use a multidimensional array, with the key set to the website eg. "www.coca-cola.com" and the values set to all of the links on that page (www.coca-cola.com/buy, www.coca-cola.com/find a product/, etc). I plan to access each of those sublinks recursively until they are all searched. However, I am running into a problem with this line of code:

```
array_push($accessedarray, ($source => $finished));
```

This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know of a better method for accomplishing this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
$accessedarray[$source] = $finished;
```